# Switch between option name in commandline option parser

Tags: c, command-line

I try to write code where switch '--feature' can have one that does the opposite effect, called '--no-feature'.

Pseudo code:

```
static gboolean
option_feature_cb (const gchar *option_name, const gchar *value, gpointer data, GError **error)
{
    if (strcmp(option_name, "no-feature") != 0)
        goto error;
    else
        x = 0;
    if (strcmp(option_name, "feature") != 0)
        goto error;
    else
        x = 1;

    return TRUE;
error:
    g_set_error(error, G_OPTION_ERROR, G_OPTION_ERROR_FAILED,
            _("invalid option name (%s), must be '--feature' or '--no-feature'"), value);
    return FALSE;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

.................................................................................................................
const GOptionEntry entries[] = {
    { "[no-]feature", '\0', 0, G_OPTION_ARG_CALLBACK, option_feature_cb, N_("Disable/enable feature"), NULL },
    { NULL }
};
```

I need help to write code to do this.

UPDATE

I find this parse commands in Ruby but I what to use this in c and gnome:

Switches can have a negated form. The switch --negated can have one that does the opposite effect, called --no-negated. To describe this in the switch description string, place the alternative portion in brackets: --[no-]negated. If the first form is encountered, true will be passed to the block, and false will be blocked if the second form is encountered.

```
options[:neg] = false
opts.on( '-n', '--[no-]negated', "Negated forms" ) do|n|
    options[:neg] = n
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test for `no-feature` prevents ever checking for `feature`, because it goes straight to `error` when it fails. The following should work better:

```
static gboolean
option_feature_cb (const gchar *option_name, const gchar *value, gpointer data, GError **error)
{
    if (strcmp(option_name, "no-feature") == 0) {
        x = 0;
        return TRUE;
    } elseif (strcmp(option_name, "feature") == 0) {
        x = 1;
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        g_set_error(error, G_OPTION_ERROR, G_OPTION_ERROR_FAILED,
            _("invalid option name (%s), must be '--feature' or '--no-feature'"), value);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```